# Claiming papers with ORCID, as a co-author

Tags: publications, authorship, digital-researcher-id

I am setting up my ORCHID iD and account and am prompted to claim my published papers. For my first authored papers it is straightforward. However I am wondering: am I also supposed to claim papers where I am a co-author? In other words, can every co-author claim a paper through ORCID or is this only reserved for first authors? I tried it out on my NASA-ADS account and it allowed me to claim non-first author papers.

Comment: Yes: if you are a co-author you can claim the work on Orcid

Comment: *or is this only reserved for first authors* --- FYI, if this were correct then I would wonder how most every multi-authored (pure) mathematics paper is be handled, since authors are listed alphabetically and the idea of a "first author" doesn't exist!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All papers that you have authored or co-authored can be indexed in orcid.